# Rails, changing the class attribute of a an HTML element when clicking on it

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing the view of a mailbox system. I wanna have **Inbox** and **Sent** mailboxes. Therefore I place two links in my view such as:

```rb
<%= link_to "Inbox", messages_user_path(current_user),:class =>"current", :which_mailbox => "received" %>
<%= link_to "Sentbox", messages_user_path(current_user),:class =>"current", :which_mailbox => "sent" %>
```

And then I expect my controller to fetch the appropiate messages according to `params[:which_mailbox]. Such as:

```rb
def fetch_messages
    if params[:which_mailbox] == "received"
      @messages= current_user.received_messages
    else if params[:which_mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = current_user.sent_messages
    end

    render 'users/messages_page'
end
```

I want to style the selected mailbox( i.e. `class="current") using bold fonts, in contrast to the other option.

```
a .current{
    font-weight: bold;    
}
```

The **problem** is that both options ( Inbox/Sentbox) have `class="current"` using the `link_to ..` code above. How can I activate/deactivate this class? Is it possible to do without Javascript? That is just using Rails+ CSS?

**EDIT**
This is the generated HTML:

```rb
    <section>
  <a href="/users/1/messages" class="current" which_mailbox="received">Inbox</a>
</section>
<section>
  <a href="/users/1/messages" class="current" which_mailbox="sent">Sent</a>
</section>
```

I realize now that there is no `params[:which_mailbox]`, I guess I should initialize the key `which_mailbox`, where is the recommended place do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do full page reloads, there's no need to involve javascript here. You can just render appropriate class.

```
<%= link_to "Inbox", messages_user_path(current_user, :which_mailbox => "received"),
                    :class => params[:which_mailbox] == 'received' ? 'current' : '' %>
```

#### You can DRY up this code a little bit by moving logic into helper

```
module MailboxesHelper
  def mailbox_link_class(this_mailbox, current)
    this_mailbox == current ? 'current' : ''
  end

  def mailbox_link(label, type)
    link_to label, messages_user_path(current_user, :which_mailbox => type),
                      :class =>mailbox_link_class(type, params[:which_mailbox])
  end
end

<%= mailbox_link 'Inbox', 'received' %>
<%= mailbox_link 'Sentbox', 'sent' %>
```

Comment: Let me get this right, using a timeline. So at **time=0** both `class=''`, and hence my page does not **bold** any link. Also both links have `:which_mailbox="value"`. Then at **time=1** I click on one of them and checks the `params[:which_mailbox]` value from the *previous* request, and changes the class accordingly? Am I getting it right? I just tried it and it doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: If there's no `params[:which_mailbox]` what content do you show?

Comment: When you click a link, request is posted with appropriate `:which_mailbox` which should appear in `params`. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: For now I always render the same content, `current_user.received_messages`, so my controller doesn't implement any logic regarding `params[:which_mailbox]` yet. I'm only testing the change in styling/css class attribute.

Comment: Ah, I see. You misplaced `which_mailbox` parameter in link creation code. So it's not passed to the server when link is clicked. See my last version (at the bottom)

Comment: You can easily implement default mailbox. I leave it for you to implement (hint: `mailbox_link_class`)

Comment: I'm using the **not-DRY** approach, since it's more straightforward to follow. And I can't seem to get it to work. I guess I'm doing something wrong, but there's no typo or anything in my code.

Comment: That's great! Thank you, I didn't spot the way you changed the parenthesis in the DRY'ed version. By the way, is the kind of 'timeline' or event sequence I explained before correct? It sets the `class="current"` observing the `params[:which_mailbox]` from the previous request, right?

Comment: @vint-i-vuit: nope. From the current request. It's always the current request, there is nothing else.

Comment: Ok, at first `params[:which_mailbox]` was actually empty. But that was because at the link to go to `Messages` pages, in my view layout. I had a `<li><%= link_to "Messages", messages_user_path(current_user) %></li>`, which had to be a `<li><%= link_to "Messages", messages_user_path(current_user,:which_mailbox=>"received") %></li>`. Hence selecting "received" by default. thanks for replying.